# Why does my object disappear when zooming in?

Tags: modeling, texture-painting

So I know usually the clip start is what allows you to zoom in to see details at close view, however I currently have it at 0.0001m. So Im trying to figure out what else could be the problem. Please and thank you!
[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: It looks like you just zoomed past the outside of the foot. Have you tried smoothly zooming in with Ctrl middle-mouse-button?

Comment: Didn't know about that hotkey but I messed with the preferences and fixed it! Thank you though! Apparently I had preferences->Navigation-> Orbit&Pan (Auto Depth) unchecked. I checked it and it fixed the problem. The zoom was just going too fast im guessing and made it where I couldn't zoom in for details. Still new to blender but thanks for answering! learned a hotkey :)